# libgdx particle system Z coordinate

Tags: java, transformation, libgdx, particle-system

I want to render a particle effect in 3D using the Z coordinate. I've tried to implement a own ParticleEffect using Decals instead of Sprites without success.

Is there any other way to render a ParticleEffect using the Z coordinate? Maybe by manipulating the transformation Matrix of the SpriteBatch?

**Update:**

working code

```
// update projection each frame since my camera is moving
spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera3d.projection);

for (ParticleEffect effect : effects){
    spriteBatch.setTransformMatrix(camera3d.view);
    spriteBatch.getTransformMatrix().translate(x,y,z); // different for each effect
    spriteBatch.getTransformMatrix().scale(0.1f,0.1f,0.1f); //optional
    spriteBatch.begin();

    effect.draw(spriteBatch, delta);

    spriteBatch.end();
    spriteBatch.getTransformMatrix().idt();
}
```

Comment: Is your game 2d or 3d?  What does "using the Z coordinate" mean?  That the particles render at different sizes on the screen?  Can you show a screenshot of what you have?

Comment: My game is 3d, but ParticleEffect of libgdx is for 2d (uses only X and Y, no Z) because it uses Sprites(2d) internally and SpriteBatch for drawing. I want the effect appear partially behind of near objects and in front of far objects with respect of the perspective.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your 3D effect is a parallax effect, meaning your particles face the camera perpendicularily, you can indeed set the transformation matrix of the SpriteBatch

```
batch.getTransformMatrix().idt().translate(0, 0, z);
batch.begin();
... do your rendering here
batch.end();
// reset the matrix, so you can use the batch for other stuff
batch.idt();
```

For a perspective effect you'll also have to use perspective projection. The easiest way to cope with this requirement is to use a PerspectiveCamera instead of an OrthographicCamera.

Comment: thank you, that was the final hint! i've updated the question with the working code. thank you for libgdx by the way!